# Spring Data and Native Query with pagination

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In a web project, using latest spring-data (1.10.2) with a MySQL 5.6 database, I'm trying to use a native query with pagination but I'm experiencing an `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.InvalidJpaQueryMethodException` at startup.

### **UPDATE**: 20180306 This issue is now fixed in [Spring 2.0.4](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA/fixforversion/16650/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel) For those still interested or stuck with older versions check the related answers and comments for workarounds.

According to [Example 50 at Using @Query from spring-data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) this is possible specifying the query itself and a countQuery, like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Out of curiosity, In `NativeJpaQuery` class I can see that it contains the following code to check if it's a valid jpa query:

```
public NativeJpaQuery(JpaQueryMethod method, EntityManager em, String queryString, EvaluationContextProvider evaluationContextProvider, SpelExpressionParser parser) {
   super(method, em, queryString, evaluationContextProvider, parser);
   JpaParameters parameters = method.getParameters();
   boolean hasPagingOrSortingParameter = parameters.hasPageableParameter() || parameters.hasSortParameter();
   boolean containsPageableOrSortInQueryExpression = queryString.contains("#pageable") || queryString.contains("#sort");
   if(hasPagingOrSortingParameter && !containsPageableOrSortInQueryExpression) {
       throw new InvalidJpaQueryMethodException("Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination in method " + method);
   }
}
```

My query contains a `Pageable` parameter, so `hasPagingOrSortingParameter` is `true`, but it's also looking for a `#pageable` or `#sort` sequence inside the `queryString`, which I do not provide.

I've tried adding `#pageable` (it's a comment) at the end of my query, which makes validation to pass but then, it fails at execution saying that the query expects one additional parameter: 3 instead of 2.

Funny thing is that, if I manually change `containsPageableOrSortInQueryExpression` from `false` to `true` while running, the query works fine so I don't know why it's checking for that string to be at my `queryString` and I don't know how to provide it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

*Update 01/30/2018*
It seems that developers at spring-data project are working on a fix for this issue with a [PR by Jens Schauder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/246)

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet. I created a ticket in Spring JIRA but there's no response: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-928.

In the end, I didn't need pagination so I haven't tried to investigate any further or push harder with that ticket.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As a workaround you could have added "\n#pageable\n" instead of "#pageable", but I hope it will be fixed in the future.

Comment: that current fix made things worse for me. now my PageAble parameter is completely ignored and the query is executed unlimited.

so if you inserted that \n#pageable\n workaround, make sure to remove it or you'll get into trouble.

Comment: For me, I was using `@Param("lastname")` annotation and the problem was `WHERE LASTNAME = \":lastname\"`, where these double quotes were unnecessary. So it was because I simply forgot to remove double quotes from these param of SQL.

Comment: As others have noted, adding `#pageable` is no longer needed on newer versions of JPA, but be sure your Pageable param has a Sort specified otherwise it will be ignored.

Answer (score 63):

My apologies in advance, this is pretty much summing up the original question and the comment from [Janar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3752185/janar), however...

I run into the same problem: I found the [Example 50 of Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) as the solution for my need of having a native query with pagination but Spring was complaining on startup that I could not use pagination with native queries.

I just wanted to report that I managed to run  successfully the native query I needed, using pagination, with the following code:

```
    @Query(value="SELECT a.* "
            + "FROM author a left outer join mappable_natural_person p on a.id = p.provenance_id "
            + "WHERE p.update_time is null OR (p.provenance_name='biblio_db' and a.update_time>p.update_time)"
            + "ORDER BY a.id \n#pageable\n", 
        /*countQuery="SELECT count(a.*) "
            + "FROM author a left outer join mappable_natural_person p on a.id = p.provenance_id "
            + "WHERE p.update_time is null OR (p.provenance_name='biblio_db' and a.update_time>p.update_time) \n#pageable\n",*/
        nativeQuery=true)
public List<Author> findAuthorsUpdatedAndNew(Pageable pageable);
```

The countQuery (that is commented out in the code block) is needed to use `Page<Author>`
as the return type of the query, the newlines around the "#pageable" comment are needed to avoid the runtime error on the number of expected parameters (workaround of the workaround). I hope this bug will be fixed soon...

Comment: In my case `?#{#pageable}` is working instead `\n#pageable\n`.

Comment: This works. 
For arguments you can still use named parameters. example `:authorId` . I changed your `\n#pageable\n` to `--#pageable\n` for postgresql. The countQuery  is needed as you suggested since many examples use List<> instead of Page<> your answer was spot on for this. I went through the same docs and if it wasn't for your answer I would have just given up.

Comment: If you don't write the countQuery and letting the framework handles that, sometime doesn't write the count by query correctly for you and you might see an error as invalid field list. You can always analyze the SQL statements by adding below entries to the property file

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

Adding the count by query separately will fix the issue. This might depend of the framework versions and the database you are using.

Comment: In my case only `/*:pageable*/` works (with SQL Server, Hibernate 5.4.1.Final and Spring Boot 2.2.1)

Comment: Is it just me or anyone else notice that `--` for Postgres and `/**/` for most of database engines means 'please, comment this bloc of code'? Am I misunderstanding the answers? Sorry if I'm reading all on the wrong side.

Answer (score 54):

This is a hack for program using **Spring Data JPA before Version 2.0.4**.

Code has worked with PostgreSQL and MySQL :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1 ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
       nativeQuery = true)
   Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);   
}
```

`ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}` is for `Pageable`.
`countQuery` is for `Page<User>`.

Comment: I don't now. Try 1. enable logging of SQL statements - set `spring.jpa.show-sql=false` in `application.properties`; 2. set `?#{#pageable}` in your nativeQuery and 3. analyse result SQL from log. @Lasneyx created issue [DATAJPA-928](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-928) for this peculiarity of Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Hello @Dmitry , what should i do next, after i got `Pageable pageable ` to make it paginated thank you?

Answer (score 20):

I am adding this answer just as a placeholder for those users who are using more recent versions of Spring Boot.  On Spring Boot 2.4.3, I observed that none of the workaround were necessary, and the following code worked straight out of the box for me:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
    Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The `countQuery` definition was not necessary, and a call to `Page#getTotalElements()` in fact already was returning the correct count, as returned by JPA's own internal count query.

The above code is extremely powerful, offering pagination made via a native query, yet which return results into actual Java entities (rather than the ugly and bulky `List<Object[]>`, which sometimes is necessary).

Comment: This worked for me, avoid using table alias in select query, it won't work!

Comment: This also worked for me in Spring boot 3. This should be answer .

Comment: but when I use alias I had to add countQuery otherwise I got oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "myAlias"   invalid identifier

Comment: Does it work if the query has complex joins? What’s the actual query that’s generated?

Comment: I get this error while using MSSQL: The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer

Answer (score 14):

Just for the record, using H2 as testing database, and MySQL at runtime, this approach works (example is [newest object in group](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/)):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.* FROM t LEFT JOIN t AS t_newer " +
        "ON t.object_id = t_newer.object_id AND t.id < t_newer.id AND o_newer.user_id IN (:user_ids) " +
        "WHERE t_newer.id IS NULL AND t.user_id IN (:user_ids) " +
        "ORDER BY t.id DESC \n-- #pageable\n",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t WHERE t.user_id IN (:user_ids) GROUP BY t.object_id, t.user_id",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<T> findByUserIdInGroupByObjectId(@Param("user_ids") Set<Integer> userIds, Pageable pageable);
```

Spring Data JPA 1.10.5, H2 1.4.194, MySQL Community Server 5.7.11-log (innodb_version 5.7.11).

Comment: Worked for PostgreSQL. Thank you!

Comment: what if we have to pass order by asc or desc dynamically to the query?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1 ORDER BY /*#pageable*/",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

(`"/*  */"` for `Oracle notation`)

Comment: some reason genreated query having comma after pageable some thing like this "ORDER BY /*#pageable*/,"  causing syntax error

Comment: i remove order by but  generated exception unexpected char: '#'

Answer (score 8):

I have exact same symptom like @Lasneyx. My workaround for Postgres native query

```
@Query(value = "select * from users where user_type in (:userTypes) and user_context='abc'--#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> getUsersByTypes(@Param("userTypes") List<String> userTypes, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Worked for me with DB2 as well.

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery = true, value= "select a.* from rqst a LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id= b.id where a.code='abc' ORDER BY --#pageable\n") is not working : Couldn't determine the data type of parameter $2

Answer (score 6):

I use oracle database and I did not get the result but an error with generated comma which d-man speak about above.

Then my solution was:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(current, rowCount);
```

As you can see without order by when create Pagable.

And the method in the DAO:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1 /*#pageable*/ ORDER BY LASTNAME",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I could successfully integrate Pagination in

> spring-data-jpa-2.1.6

as follows.

```
@Query(
 value = “SELECT * FROM Users”, 
 countQuery = “SELECT count(*) FROM Users”, 
 nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllUsersWithPagination(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Where pageable parameter in the native query?

Answer (score 2):

Both the following approaches work fine with MySQL for paginating native query. They doesn't work with H2 though. It will complain the sql syntax error.

- ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}
- ORDER BY a.id \n#pageable\n

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (I am using Postgres) in Groovy:

```
@RestResource(path="namespaceAndNameAndRawStateContainsMostRecentVersion", rel="namespaceAndNameAndRawStateContainsMostRecentVersion")
    @Query(nativeQuery=true,
            countQuery="""
            SELECT COUNT(1) 
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY name, provider_id, state
                    ORDER BY version DESC) version_partition,
                *
                FROM mydb.mytable
                WHERE
                (name ILIKE ('%' || :name || '%') OR (:name = '')) AND
                (namespace ILIKE ('%' || :namespace || '%') OR (:namespace = '')) AND
                (state = :state OR (:state = ''))
            ) t
            WHERE version_partition = 1
            """,
            value="""
            SELECT id, version, state, name, internal_name, namespace, provider_id, config, create_date, update_date 
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY name, provider_id, state
                    ORDER BY version DESC) version_partition,
                *
                FROM mydb.mytable
                WHERE 
                (name ILIKE ('%' || :name || '%') OR (:name = '')) AND
                (namespace ILIKE ('%' || :namespace || '%') OR (:namespace = '')) AND
                (state = :state OR (:state = ''))       
            ) t            
            WHERE version_partition = 1             
            /*#{#pageable}*/
            """)
    public Page<Entity> findByNamespaceContainsAndNameContainsAndRawStateContainsMostRecentVersion(@Param("namespace")String namespace, @Param("name")String name, @Param("state")String state, Pageable pageable)
```

The key here was to use: `/*#{#pageable}*/`

It allows me to do sorting and pagination.
You can test it by using something like this: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/entities/search/namespaceAndNameAndRawStateContainsMostRecentVersion?namespace=&name=&state=published&page=0&size=3&sort=name,desc

Watch out for this issue: [Spring Pageable does not translate @Column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459684/spring-pageable-does-not-translate-column-name)

Answer (score 1):

Using "ORDER BY id DESC \n-- #pageable\n " 
instead of "ORDER BY id \n#pageable\n" worked for me with MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1):

- Create your custom repository:

```java
public interface ProductsCustomRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductResultEntity, Long> {
    @Query(
        value = "select tableA.id, tableB.bank_name from tableA join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.a_id where tableA.id = :id
        and (:fieldX is null or tableA.fieldX LIKE :fieldX)",
        countQuery = "select count(*) from tableA join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.a_id where tableA.id = :id
        and (:fieldX is null or tableA.fieldX LIKE :fieldX)",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    Page<ProductResultEntity> search(@Param("id") Long aId,
        @Param("fieldX") String keyword, Pageable pageable
    );
}
```

- Create View as query of:

```sql
create view zzz as select * from tableA join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.a_id
```

- Generate ProductResultEntity from that *zzz* view (and delete view zzz when have done)
- Test call function and enjoy it:

```java
productsRepository.search("123", "%BANK%", PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id")));
```

- Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class ProductResultEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String bank;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "bank_name", nullable = false)
    public String getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    public void setBank(String bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity generate by View which uses that tool in Inteliji: Persistence or you can write it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

For me below worked in MS SQL

```
 @Query(value="SELECT * FROM ABC r where r.type in :type  ORDER BY RAND() \n-- #pageable\n ",nativeQuery = true)
List<ABC> findByBinUseFAndRgtnType(@Param("type") List<Byte>type,Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using the code below. working**

```
@Query(value = "select * from user usr" +
  "left join apl apl on usr.user_id = apl.id" +
  "left join lang on lang.role_id = usr.role_id" +
  "where apl.scr_name like %:scrname% and apl.uname like %:uname and usr.role_id in :roleIds ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
  countQuery = "select count(*) from user usr" +
      "left join apl apl on usr.user_id = apl.id" +
      "left join lang on lang.role_id = usr.role_id" +
      "where apl.scr_name like %:scrname% and apl.uname like %:uname and usr.role_id in :roleIds",
  nativeQuery = true)
Page<AplUserEntity> searchUser(@Param("scrname") String scrname,@Param("uname") String  uname,@Param("roleIds") List<Long> roleIds,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Please can you explain why this answer is better than any of the others that have been around for several years?

Answer (score 0):

Removing \n#pageable\n from both query and count query worked for me.
Springboot version : 2.1.5.RELEASE
DB : Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for h2 and MySQl

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT req.CREATED_AT createdAt, req.CREATED_BY createdBy,req.APP_ID appId,req.NOTE_ID noteId,req.MODEL model FROM SUMBITED_REQUESTS  req inner join NOTE note where req.NOTE_ID=note.ID and note.CREATED_BY= :userId "
        ,
         countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM SUMBITED_REQUESTS req inner join NOTE note WHERE req.NOTE_ID=note.ID and note.CREATED_BY=:userId",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserRequestsDataMapper> getAllRequestForCreator(@Param("userId") String userId,Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score -1):

**It does work as below:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from (select (@rowid\\:=@rowid+1) as RN, u.* from USERS u, (SELECT @rowid\\:=0) as init where  LASTNAME = ?1) as total"+
        "where RN between ?#{#pageable.offset-1} and ?#{#pageable.offset + #pageable.pageSize}",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
    Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by using following code,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users u WHERE  ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> getUsers(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Simply use **ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}** and pass page request to your method.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

```
@Query(value = "select " +
//"row_number() over (order by ba.order_num asc) as id, " +
"row_number() over () as id, " +
"count(ba.order_num),sum(ba.order_qty) as sumqty, " +
"ba.order_num, " +
"md.dpp_code,md.dpp_name, " +
"from biz_arrangement ba " +
"left join mst_dpp md on ba.dpp_code = md.dpp_code " +
"where 1 = 1 " +
"AND (:#{#flilter.customerCodeListCheck}='' OR ba.customer_code IN (:#{#flilter.customerCodeList})) " +
"AND (:#{#flilter.customerNameListCheck}='' OR ba.customer_name IN (:#{#flilter.customerNameList})) " +
"group by " +
"ba.order_num, " +
"md.dpp_code,md.dpp_name ",
countQuery = "select " +
"count ( " +
"distinct ( " +
"ba.order_num, " +
"md.dpp_code,md.dpp_name) " +
")" +
"from biz_arrangement ba " +
"left join mst_dpp md on ba.dpp_code = md.dpp_code " +
"where 1 = 1 " +
"AND (:#{#flilter.customerCodeListCheck}='' OR ba.customer_code IN (:#{#flilter.customerCodeList})) " +
"AND (:#{#flilter.customerNameListCheck}='' OR ba.customer_name IN (:#{#flilter.customerNameList})) ",
nativeQuery = true)
Page<Map<String, Object>> nativeQueryDynamicPageAndSort(@Param("flilter") Flilter flilter, Pageable pageable);
```

no need to add ?#{#pageable},
the problem I got is when I use

```
row_number() over (order by ba.order_num asc) as id,
```

the input sort won't work
when I change to

```
row_number() over () as id,
```

the dynamic input sort and pagination are both okay!

This is a group by query with a row id.

Answer (score -2):

Replacing /*#pageable*/ with ?#{#pageable} allow to do pagination.
Adding PageableDefault allow you to set size of page Elements.