# creating Spring Repository Select using multiple "like" and Pageable

Tags: java, sql, spring-data, h2

I'm using H2-Database and Spring-Data PagingRepository. I like to use paging and select all *articles* from database that field *html* contains *'@'* or *'[at]'* or *'(at)'* or *'mail'* ...

So the native query without paging looks like

```
SELECT * FROM article  WHERE (html LIKE '%@%' or html LIKE '%(at)%' or html LIKE '%[at]%' or ...)
```

I tried to solve it like this:

```
Page<Article> findByHtmlContainingOrderByDateDesc(String[] string,  Pageable pageable);
```

But there is no/empty result.

Second way I tried is using a native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM article  WHERE (html LIKE '%@%' or html LIKE '%(at)%') ORDER BY DATE desc \n#pageable\n" , 
nativeQuery = true,
countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM article  WHERE (html LIKE '%@%' or html LIKE '%(at)%')")
Page<Article> findAll(@Param("pageable") Pageable pageable);
```

But I'm getting the exception:

*nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root cause*

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination there are db dependent variations of the #pageable magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, that worked for me was adding `\n-- #pageable\n` to the custom query. So I ended up at

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM article  WHERE (html LIKE '%@%' or html LIKE '%(at)%') ORDER BY DATE desc \n-- #pageable\n" , nativeQuery = true,
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM article  WHERE (html LIKE '%@%' or html LIKE '%(at)%')")
Page<Article> findAll(@Param("pageable") Pageable pageable);
```