# Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination even if I have specified the count query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**@Query(
value = "select * from paper_entry where owner is null or owner = ?1",
countQuery = "select count(*) from paper_entry where owner is not null or owner = ?1",
nativeQuery = true)**

**Page findAll(Long userId, Pageable pageable);**

I use mysql 5.7, spring-data-jpa 1.11.3.RELEASE. As you can see, I follow the document https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query. However I got this error.

Caused by: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.InvalidJpaQueryMethodException: Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination in method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.gbdata.entry.persistence.dao.PaperEntryRepository.findAll(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NativeJpaQuery.(NativeJpaQuery.java:55) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at ........

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination) it may help.

Comment: @ControlAltDel it's all there

Answer (score 35, accepted):

解决没? SQL里面加 `ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}` 就可以了

```
@Query(
        value = "select * from paper_entry where owner is null or owner = ?1 ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
        countQuery = "select count(*) from paper_entry where owner is not null or owner = ?1 ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
        nativeQuery = true)
    Page findAll(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

It's duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination).

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer, in the future