# Write sql native query with left join and pagination in hibernate (springboot)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data JPA and I want to write a SQL query in my repository.

I have a following SQL query (notice the LEFT JOIN):

```
SELECT * FROM institution LEFT JOIN 
(select * from building_institutions where building_institutions.building_id = 1) as reserved_institutions
ON reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id = institution.user_id
WHERE reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id is null;
```

and i want to execute it in my InstitutionRepository which is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface InstitutionRepository extends JpaRepository<Institution, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Institution,Long> {
    // doesn't work
    //@Query("SELECT b.institutions as bi FROM Building b left join Institution i WHERE bi.building_id not in :id")
    Page<Institution> findPotentialInstitutionsByBuildingId(@Param("id") Collection<Long> id, Pageable pageable);

    // doesn't work    
    @Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM kits_nwt.institution LEFT JOIN\n" +
                    "(SELECT * FROM kits_nwt.building_institutions WHERE kits_nwt.building_institutions.building_id = ?1) AS reserved_institutions\n" +
                    "ON reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id = kits_nwt.institution.user_id\n" +
                    "WHERE reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id IS null ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Institution> findPotentialInstitutionsByBuildingId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

So, I want to get all institutions which are not in building with certain ID (which I will send as a parameter).

### Here is my current DB data:

**Institutions:**

[image: Institutions]

**Building institutions:**

[image: Building institutions]

**What I want:** (in this query, the id is set on 1, for presentation purposes)

[image: What I want]

I have looked at many SO questions and answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)) but I haven't been able to figure out the solution.

So, how do I write this query so that I get what I want?

### Edit 1:

@KevinAnderson Currently, I'm trying with:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT username, password, description, location, title, user_id FROM (institution INNER JOIN user ON institution.user_id = user.id) LEFT JOIN\n" +
                "(SELECT * FROM building_institutions WHERE building_institutions.building_id = 1) AS reserved_institutions\n" +
                "ON reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id = kits_nwt.institution.user_id\n" +
                "WHERE reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id IS null ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Institution> findPotentialInstitutionsByBuildingId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

And I'm getting this exception:

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE) FROM building_institutions WHERE building_institutions.building_id = 1) A' at line 2

### Edit 2:

@StanislavL here it is:

[image]

The problem is that your query gets me the institution with ID 25 because it is in both building with ID 1 and building with ID 2. When you do a JOIN, you have 2 rows ON institution ID being 25 in both institution table and building_institutions table. Then, your WHERE condition removes one from those two rows and I get one row where instituiton ID is 25, and I don't want what.

Here is an image for the above:

[image: Join without WHERE]

### Edit 3 - this question is not a duplicate because of the following:

- My query is with pagination (I added "with pagination" to the question title)
- I'm not using `@NamedQuery` but `@Query`
- My mistake was that I didn't write countQuery parameter to the `@Query` annotation

Comment: If you can't figure out a solution doesn't mean that it doesn't have one.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I'll edit my question with what I'm trying right now.

Comment: @RomanC I didn't say it doesn't have one. I'm hoping that it HAS one and that someone in the SO community knows what it is and is willing to help me.

Comment: @FilipSavic No, if don't understand the problem in your question you cannot say that someone willing to help you. It's not help and support.

Comment: @RomanC I edited the question (Edit 3) to argument why it is not a duplicate

Comment: @RomanC it is not a duplicate - named query is different than native-query - I upvoted both answer and question since this solved my problem

Comment: @RomanC it is duplicate of this question and not the one showing up there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it...

The query needs to look like this:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM \n" +
                "(institution INNER JOIN user ON institution.user_id = user.id) \n" +
                "LEFT JOIN \n" +
                "(SELECT * FROM \n" +
                "building_institutions \n" +
                "WHERE building_id = :userId)\n" +
                " AS reserved_institutions \n" +
                "ON reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id = kits_nwt.institution.user_id \n" +
                " where reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id IS null \n"
                + "ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"
        ,
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM \n" +
                "(institution INNER JOIN user ON institution.user_id = user.id) \n" +
                "LEFT JOIN \n" +
                "(SELECT * FROM \n" +
                "building_institutions \n" +
                "WHERE building_id =:userId)\n" +
                " AS reserved_institutions \n" +
                "ON reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id = kits_nwt.institution.user_id \n" +
                "where reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id IS null \n" +
                "ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Institution> findPotentialInstitutionsByBuildingId(@Param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

I was getting the error at line 4 near WHERE, when my query looked like this:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT username, password, description, location, title, user_id FROM (institution INNER JOIN user ON institution.user_id = user.id) LEFT JOIN\n" +
                "(SELECT * FROM building_institutions WHERE building_institutions.building_id = 1) AS reserved_institutions\n" +
                "ON reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id = kits_nwt.institution.user_id\n" +
                "WHERE reserved_institutions.institutions_user_id IS null ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Institution> findPotentialInstitutionsByBuildingId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

and that was because I didn't add the `countQuery` parameter to the `@Query` annotation.

Big thanks to all of you who tried to help.

I hope that I save someone else many hours of misery.

Cheers! :)

Comment: wow saved my day thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: I was very struggling with it for long time, but eventually found your self-answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure! :))