# Spring Jpa findBy method to fetch top results

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a table with below data.

```
Name    Version
----    -------
ABC      1.0
ABC      1.1
BCD      1.0
BCD      1.1
BCD      1.2
```

and I am trying to write a spring data jpa findBy method to query all names with latest versions. So my result should be

```
Name     Version
----     -------
ABC      1.1
BCD      1.2
```

I tried

```
findByTopVersionDesc
findByDistinctTopNameDescVersionDesc
findByFirstNameDescVersionDesc
```

and other combinations but couldn't make this work. Any suggestions

Comment: I don't think that you can do that with just declaring a method. How would you do that with SQL?

Comment: @Query(value = "select d.name, d.version from entity d inner join (select distinct name, MAX(version) as version from entity group by name) as a on d.name = a.name where d.version = a.version", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Entity> findLatestDomainInstances();   it has been written with nativequery. Now we want to return page object and trying to utilize datarest with pagingandsorting repository. While doing, Spring doesn't support paging with Native query as per some other sources in google and I am trying to write this query using findBy method

Comment: Looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination it seems pagination is supported with native queries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the way you are writing the method name is wrong:

[Spring Docs for what you are trying to do](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)