# Spring data JPA nativeQuery order by is invalid

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The Spring Data Jpa Method like this:

```
@Query("select pb.id,pp.max_borrow_amt,pp.min_borrow_amt
from product_loan_basic pb left join product_loan_price pp on pb.code=pp.product_code 
 where pb.code IN(?1) and pb.status='publish' order by  ?2 ",
nativeQuery = true)  
List<Object[]> findByCodesIn(List<String> codes,String orderby);
```

then order by is " max_borrow_amt desc ", but this is invalid.
the List is disordered.

Comment: You can not set the order by as parameter in prepared statement

Answer (score 16):

### Dynamic sorting in Spring Data JPA

If you used a JPA query you could use [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting) as an argument of your query method to define the sorting order:

```
@Query("select m from Model m")
List<Model> getSortedList(Sort sort);
```

and then, for example:

```
List<Model> models = getSortedList(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"));
```

But Spring Data JPA [can't use](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries) `Sort` with native queries:

> Spring Data JPA does not currently support dynamic sorting for native queries, because it would have to manipulate the actual query declared, which it cannot do reliably for native SQL.

However you can use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) and its implementation [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) instead:

```
@Query(value = "select m.name as name from models m", nativeQuery = true)
List<ModelProjection> getSortedList(Pageable p);
```

and then:

```
List<ModelProjection> modelNames = getSortedList(PageRequest.of(0, 1000, Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"));
```

P.S. Instead of array of `Object`s as returned parameters, it's better to use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), for example:

```
public interface ModelProjection {
    String getName();
}
```

Note that in this case the good practice is to use aliases in queries (ie `m.name as name`). They must match with correspondent getters in the projection.

Working [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/native-query-sorting-demo) and [test](https://github.com/Cepr0/native-query-sorting-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/ModelRepoTest.java).

Comment: That only work if you are in one table. A JOIN Table not work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone!
My problem has been solved.

If you want to use Spring data jpa `nativeQuery` & Sort, you should do like this:

```
 @Query(
          value ="select pb.id,pp.max_borrow_amt from product_loan_basic pb left join product_loan_price pp on pb.code=pp.product_code ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}  ",
          countQuery = "select count(*) from product_loan_basic",
          nativeQuery = true
  )
  Page<Object[]> findAllProductsAndOrderByAndSort(Pageable pageable);
```

`?#{#pageable}` is required and `countQuery` is required.

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0,1000,Sort.Direction.DESC,"id");
```

then the result is sorted.

See [Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination).

Comment: see [Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)

Comment: In the latest version of Spring Boot it's not necessary to use those trick with `?#{#pageable}`. See my [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/native-query-sorting-demo) and its [test](https://github.com/Cepr0/native-query-sorting-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/ModelRepoTest.java).

Comment: @Cepr0 can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465994/unable-to-sort-using-org-springframewrk-data-domain-sort-for-2-date-fields