# Unable to sort using org.springframewrk.data.domain.Sort for 2 date fields

Tags: spring-boot, sorting, jpa, psql

I want to set the below ordering ie

```
select * from table order by (date(closedDate)-date(openDate)) desc ;
```

The above query gives the expected result but I want to achieve the same using the sort function

ie

I am using

```
 import org.springframewrk.data.domain.*;

    Sort sort=Sort.by(openDate).descending();
  Pageable paging=PageRequest.of(1,10,sort);
```

This works well for 1 date field but If I use 2 date fields I am getting *invalid expression for sort*

I want something like

```
Sort sort=Sort.by(closedDate-openDate).descending();
```

Is it possible to achieve this using the sort function