# How to sort by pagerequest with inner join

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I have two tables with many to one realtion. I want to sort data in table "user" by column "street" that is in "address" table in ASC or DESC direction defined by request param:

```
localhost:8080/getUsers?sort=address,desc
```

When I execute sql script:

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN address ON user.address_id=address.id ORDER BY street DESC
```

in workbench or phpMyAdmin it works good. All data are sorted by street name;

But when i try get it in postman by:

```
getUsers?sort=address,desc
```

I have this error in console output:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'INNER.address' in 'order clause'
```

Where is problem?

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
}

@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    private Long id;
    private String street
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private List<User> user;
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN address ON user.address_id=address.id",
        countQuery = "SELECT * FROM contact_messages INNER JOIN contact_topics ON contact_messages.contact_topic_id=contact_topics.id",
        nativeQuery = true)
     Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable); 
}
```

Also when i wrote query in repository like this it works as good as in workbench:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN address ON user.address_id=address.id ORDER BY address DESC",
        countQuery = "SELECT * FROM contact_messages INNER JOIN contact_topics ON contact_messages.contact_topic_id=contact_topics.id ORDER BY address DESC",
        nativeQuery = true)
```

But i want to have controll of request and sort data when i want (using sort param).

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the SQL to 
    SELECT u, a FROM user u INNER JOIN u.address a ORDER BY street DESC

Comment: `Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'u' {originalText=u}`

Comment: this works:
`SELECT u FROM user u INNER JOIN u.address a ORDER BY street DESC`

is there a possibility to add `where address like '%:param%`; to this HQL ?

Comment: SELECT u, a.street FROM user u INNER JOIN u.address a WHERE a.street LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%')")  ORDER BY a.street