# Native query is returning all the records for the #pageable in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I gone through this in stackoverflow for the pagination in native queries, No error while returning records. It is giving all records instead of taking parameter value in pageable ex: iam passing these pageSize(5 or 4) and pageNo(0) to pageable parameter.

```java
@Query(value = "select * from job_post where comp_addr_ref_id not in"
            + "(select mapping_id from company_address where ref_company_id in"
            + "(select mapping_id from  company where mapping_id in"
            + "(select comp_ref_id from comp_visibility where is_comp_visible=0 and login_ref_id=:mappingId)))"
            + " order by created_date desc  \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<JobPost> findUserBlockedCompanies(String mappingId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: hey sory i dint see, iam using mysql

Comment: Hai, can you please help me out for this query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot 2.0 or higher, try to delete `\n#pageable\n` section.

If you use PostgreSql and MySql change the value `\n#pageable\n` to
`?#{#pageable}`

If it still doesn't work you can enable logging of SQL statements using `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in your `application.properties`

Comment: If method argument name is equal to query parameter placeholder (**mappingId** in this case), then you don't have to put explicit `@Param` as it will be done by Spring implicitly

Comment: These everything i tried it..bcz it's already i seen in some blog and stak overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
If you are using Spring Data prior to 2.0.4, then you can try to replace

`\n#pageable\n`

with

`\n /* --#pageable */ \n`

This works for Postgres and Oracle.

P.S. In Spring Data 2.0.4+ you can completely remove this pageable token from query as it's not required anymore (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-928)

See also [Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38349930/2224047)

Comment: Hai sory for delay..i tried this \n /* --#pageable */ \n but still it is returning all records..Iam using mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed in oracle. My way is:

> 1-> write  `order by created_date OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :pageSize ROWS ONLY`
> to your main query
>
> 2-> create count query for your main query
>
> 3-> and you can unit your datas with `new PageIml<>(mainQueryResult, PageRequest.of(page,size), countQueryResult);`

it works for all dbs