# Convert mysql query to jpa query with pagination supported

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have mysql query for joining 3 tables, how can i convert this into JPA with pagination supported.
query :

```
SELECT promotion.name, 
       promotion.promotion_type, 
       promotion.start_date, 
       promotion.end_date, 
       promotion_history.`count`                 AS order_count, 
       Count(user_promotion_history.promotionid) AS user_count 
FROM   promotion 
       INNER JOIN user_promotion_history 
               ON promotion.promotionid = user_promotion_history.promotionid 
       INNER JOIN promotion_history 
               ON promotion.promotionid = promotion_history.promotionid 
WHERE  promotion.status = "created" 
GROUP  BY promotion.name, 
          promotion.promotionid, 
          promotion.promotion_type, 
          promotion.start_date, 
          promotion.end_date, 
          order_count;
```

I have created all entity and repository classes and used native query,

```
@Query(value = "select promotion.name, promotion.promotion_type, promotion.start_date, promotion.end_date" +
           " promotion_history.count as order_count, count(user_promotion_history.promotionid) as user_count" +
           " from promotion" +
           " inner JOIN user_promotion_history on" +
           " promotion.promotionid = user_promotion_history.promotionid" +
           " inner join promotion_history on" +
           " promotion.promotionid = promotion_history.promotionid" +
           " where promotion.status = :status" +
           " group by" +
           " promotion.name, promotion.promotionid, promotion.promotion_type, promotion.start_date,promotion.end_date, order_count",
nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findByStatus(@Param("status")PromotionStatus status);
```

but getting an error like this.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.count as order_count, count(user_promotion_history.promotionid)
>   as user_count f' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination

Comment: There is a missing comma between ***promotion.end_date*** and ***promotion_history.count as order_count***. But this error is not related to pagination. This is a syntax error. There are possible different ways to implement pagination (pagination)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging]. Also read key-set pagination https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/

Comment: thanks. joining working fine now. for pagination have used below approach, but still getting error, pls help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination i have used Pageable parameter.
@Query(value = "select promotion.name, promotion.promotion_type, promotion.start_date, promotion.end_date," +
            " promotion_history.count as order_count, count(user_promotion_history.promotionid) as user_count" +
            " from promotion" +
            " join user_promotion_history on" +
            " promotion.promotionid = user_promotion_history.promotionid" +
            " join promotion_history on" +
            " promotion.promotionid = promotion_history.promotionid" +
            " where promotion.status = ?1" +
            " group by" +
            " promotion.name, promotion.promotionid, promotion.promotion_type, promotion.start_date,promotion.end_date, order_count \n-- #pageable\n",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List findByStatus(String status, Pageable pageable);

when i see query looks like this, 
Hibernate: select promotion.name, promotion.promotion_type, promotion.start_date, promotion.end_date, promotion_history.count as order_count, count(user_promotion_history.promotionid) as user_count from promotion join user_promotion_history on promotion.promotionid = user_promotion_history.promotionid join promotion_history on promotion.promotionid = promotion_history.promotionid where promotion.status = ? group by promotion.name, promotion.promotionid, promotion.promotion_type, promotion.start_date,promotion.end_date, order_count 
-- #pageable
 order by join.user_count desc limit ?

error says : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper Unknown column 'join.user_count' in 'order clause'

somewhere "join." is getting added in order by clause.