# JPA nativeQuery with UNION does not support pagination

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following tables:

TABLE A

| id | sys_time | user_id | rent_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

TABLE B

| id | sys_time | occur_time |
| --- | --- | --- |

I would like to use a UNION query in MYSQL to have this table and put data from both tables row by row with sys_time order:

TABLE AB

| id | sys_time | user_id | occur_time | rent_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I use the following query:

```
select id, sys_time, user_id, null as occur_time, rent_time from open_close
union
select id, sys_time, null as user_id, occur_time, null as rent_time from periodic 
order by sys_time desc;
```

Now I define an @Entity with the following structure:

```
...
@Data
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name="TotalEntity.getTotal"
        , query="select id, sys_time, user_id, null as occur_time, rent_time from open_close\r\n"
                + "union\r\n"
                + "select id, sys_time, null as user_id, occur_time, null as rent_time from periodic \r\n"          + "order by sys_time desc;"
        , resultClass=TotalEntity.class
    ) 
...
// Entity Fields and so on
```

and the corresponding Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TotalRepository extends JpaRepository<TotalEntity, BigInteger> {

     @Query(nativeQuery = true)
     public List<TotalEntity> getTotal();

}
```

Everything is OK up to now.

Now I want to add pagination:

```
 @Repository
 public interface TotalRepository extends JpaRepository<TotalEntity, BigInteger> {

      @Query(nativeQuery = true)
      public Page<TotalEntity> getTotal(Pageable page);
}
```

and use this:

```
...
private TotalRepository tr;
...


Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size,
                direction.toUpperCase().equals("ASC") ? Sort.by(sort).ascending() : Sort.by(sort).descending());

        Optional<Page<TotalEntity>> pe = Optional.ofNullable(tr.getTotal(pageable));
```

The following exception is thrown:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 20' at line 4

It seems that Hibernate can not modify the nativeQuery to add pagination statements. And I know that JPQL and JPA does not supprt UNIONs. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I don't have a problem with pagination itself, the union is making some issues.

Comment: As a small workaround idea, you could define a database view with the "select union section" and execute the query on the view.

Comment: @lzagkaretos Nice Idea. It worked. Thanks! You may submit this as an answer. I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be to introduce a **view** in the database layer with the union clause, and then execute the query upon the view.

This way, you can *hide* the *union* from JPA layer and queries can be executed using `pageable` as usual.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
select id, sys_time, user_id, null as occur_time, rent_time from open_close
union
select id, sys_time, null as user_id, occur_time, null as rent_time from periodic
```

And modify the `JpaRepository` to query upon the view using prefered way, like native queries, column projections etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to use other functionalities from `Pageable` interface like getting the total records count, number of current slice etc., then try using `offset` and `limit` keywords in the query directly for the pagination.

> Note : `offeset` corresponds to page and `limit` corresponds to size of content in the page