# JPA Repository nativeQuery with pageable, join table not working when pageable.size = 1

Tags: java, sql, jpa, repository, nativequery

I have this sql query that works fine

```
SELECT ppd.userId, AVG(Coalesce(sm.score, 0)) AS avgScore
    FROM Table1 ppd 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 sm ON ppd.userId = sm.userId AND sm.created BETWEEN start AND end
    WHERE ppd.someId IN (listOfIds) 
    GROUP BY ppd.userId ORDER BY avgScore DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

I have written a query for a method in a JPARepository that looks like the following

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ppd.userId, AVG(Coalesce(sm.score, 0)) AS avgScore " +
            " FROM Table1 ppd " +
            " LEFT JOIN Table2 sm ON sm.userId = ppd.userId AND sm.created BETWEEN :start AND :end " +
            " WHERE ppd.someId IN (:IdList) GROUP BY ppd.userId",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<MyDtoProjection> getAvg(@Param("IdList") List<String> IdList,
                                 @Param("start") Long start,
                                 @Param("end") Long end,
                                 Pageable pageable);
```

Which works just as expected except when the pageable size is 1 (SQL query with Limit 1 works fine).
For the pageable parameter the service sends the following pageable object

```
Sort sort = JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.ASC, "(avgScore)");
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(offset, limit, sort);
```

The request sets offset=0 and limit=1

The error I'm receiving from request using repository code is this one:
`Unknown column 'ppd' in 'field list'\nQuery is: select count(ppd)...`, I don't know why it is taking the alias ppd as a column name, also, I read from another post that this way of executing native queries performs a count (which can be seen in the error message, I did not specify that count query), and that it can be specified by setting countQuery parameter, but I'm not sure what to write there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve it>
Just added the countQuery to the @Query annotation, I was not so sure what to place there, but it was simple

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ppd.userId, AVG(Coalesce(sm.score, 0)) AS avgScore " +
            " FROM Table1 ppd " +
            " LEFT JOIN Table2 sm ON sm.userId = ppd.userId AND sm.created BETWEEN :start AND :end " +
            " WHERE ppd.someId IN (:IdList) GROUP BY ppd.userId",
       countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(ppd.userId) FROM Table1 ppd " +
            "WHERE ppd.userId IN (:IdList) GROUP BY ppd.userId",
       nativeQuery = true)
    Page<MyDtoProjection> getAvg(@Param("IdList") List<String> IdList,
                                 @Param("start") Long start,
                                 @Param("end") Long end,
                                 Pageable pageable);
```

This is the only post I found that mentions the countQuery and how it works in one of the answers, go check it out if someone is going through the same
[Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)

Comment: Agree. With new versions of spring countQuery was enough, worked even with aliases. (My Spring Boot verison was 2.1)