# Query in spring boot with Distinct doesn't return diffrent values

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I have two classes Port and Person. a Person can have many port so there ManyToOne relationship between the two classes. I want to return all the Port that exists in Person.
here is Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    private String age;

    @Column(name = "mdp")
    private String mdp;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "puerto_id")
    private Port port;
    //getters & setters
```

here is Port class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "port")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Port implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
```

In **PortRepository.java** I made this Query that I call in PortResource.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface PortRepository extends JpaRepository<Port, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM port t1 INNER JOIN person t2 ON t1.ID = t2.puerto_id", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Port> findPersonsPorts(Pageable pageable);
}

//
@GetMapping("/persons/ports")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Port>> getPersonsPorts(@org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Ports");
        Page<Port> page = portRepository.findPersonsPorts(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

On postman when execute this **http://localhost:8080/api/people** I have the following response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2902,
        "age": "88",
        "mdp": null,
        "port": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3001,
        "age": "45",
        "mdp": "mdp",
        "port": {
            "id": 2952,
            "city": "rabat"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3002,
        "age": "88",
        "mdp": "mdp",
        "port": {
            "id": 2952,
            "city": "rabat"
        }
    } ]
```

and when send this request http://localhost:8080/api/persons/ports i get **duplicate** values of Port

```
[
    {
        "id": 2952,
        "city": "rabat"
    },
    {
        "id": 2952,
        "city": "rabat"
    } ]
```

UPDATE:

when i execute the same query on h2 database which is :
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM PORT t1 INNER JOIN PERSON t2 ON t2.puerto_id = t1.ID

I got this table, as you can see the rows are diffrent because it returns in the same table the columns of person and port table. Im not sure if this is the problem
[image]

Comment: why do you use JOIN statement, as I check your web-service it seems that you just return all the ports in your table, if you wanted to return specific ports of a single person using JOIN could be a solution but why now you are using it?

Comment: also when you use JOIN statement you need to define ON clause for it, which i don't see in your query

Comment: @Sobhan I have a lot of port records but I'm only intersted in ports that exist in Person (the ports that thier ID exist in person table like a foreign key) So I searched on the internt I found that this will be possible only with JOIN statement

Comment: @Sobhan I modified it by adding ON but still doesn't work

Comment: try with this one:
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM port t1 INNER JOIN person t2 ON t1.ID = t2.puerto_id where t2.puerto_id is not null

Comment: @Sobhan unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: this one will work for your requirements, without JOIN: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM port t1 where t2.puerto_id is not null

Comment: I got this error using query without JOIN and I guess it's obvious since t2 is not linked to person table `"detail": "could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT DISTINCT * FROM port t1 where t2.puerto_id is not null limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement",`

Comment: what is that "limit ?" at the end of your query?

Comment: I have no idea, i google it but I found nothing

Comment: check out these answers for using Pageable with native-query and the way of implementing it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination

but i myself when want to use native query i use the database functions for pagination like below for oracle DB:

SELECT DISTINCT o2.* FROM USERS u2 
INNER JOIN ORDERS o2 ON u2.ID = o2.USER_ID  
WHERE o2.USER_ID IS NOT null
OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :length ROWS ONLY

Comment: @Sobhan okey i will try it but please can you see my update above it may help us finding the error

Comment: i think your distinct keyword does not work because each of your records is uniqe because of the different ID --> 3001, 3002
if you just want the port data use "t1.*" instead of "*"

Comment: OMG !! it works thank you soooo much

Comment: I write my solution as an answer for you, Good Luck buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `DISTINCT` keyword does not work because your result set is not really unique, look at your records, `ID` column has different data, so they are not the same and `DISTINCT` does not help you.

if you just want the PORT table data try to use `t1.*` instead of `*`

use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM PORT t1 INNER JOIN PERSON t2 ON t2.puerto_id = t1.ID
```