# PostgreSQL Union query not working in JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The below PostgreSQL query works correct in pgAdmin.

```
(select * from posts where id = 1) union (select * from posts);
```

but when written in Spring Data JPA it doesn't work.

```
   @Query(value = "(select * from posts where id = 1) union (select * from posts)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Post> getPosts(Pageable pageable);
```

It gives an exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
  Position: 15
```

i want to have a union of the two select statements but the union query is not working in JPA.

Comment: How about 
```
select * from ((select * from posts where id = 1) union (select * from posts)) as subquery
```
as your query? This is a query where the framework can append its WHERE clause without a syntax error.

Comment: Do you have access to the PostgreSQL server? Can you provide the relevant entries in the error-log? It would help understand what query the framework actually produces that contains the syntax error.

Comment: @SebDieBln Thanks The approach you mentioned works out for me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I posted the approach as an answer. If you mark it as "accepted" it will help other people to know it solved your issue.

Comment: It's occurring due to the `Pageable` you are passing. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
select
  *
from (
  (select * from posts where id = 1)
  union
  (select * from posts)
) as subquery
```

as your query? This is a query where the framework can append its WHERE clause without a syntax error.