# Spring native query with GROUP BY and ORDER BY also pagination

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jpa, hibernate-native-query

What if I have my native query (with PostgreSQL) in a more "complex" way, which I need to GROUP the data in order to apply an ORDER BY clause? Well, doing so with native query (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)) the ORDER BY attributes are placed at the end of the query, which raises a SQL syntax error (of course) cause the ORDER BY should stay BEFORE my pagination clauses.

```
@Query(
        " SELECT * FROM (" +
                "SELECT CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR) AS id, t.name, CAST(COUNT(p.id) AS SMALLINT) AS usedByProjectsCount " +
                "FROM tag t " +
                "LEFT JOIN project_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id " +
                "LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = pt.project_id " +
                "GROUP BY t.id, t.name) AS t " +
                "ORDER BY #pageable " +
                "LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ",
        countQuery = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (" +
                "SELECT CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR) AS id, t.name, CAST(COUNT(p.id) AS SMALLINT) AS usedByProjectsCount " +
                "FROM tag t " +
                "LEFT JOIN project_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id " +
                "LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = pt.project_id " +
                "GROUP BY t.id, t.name) AS t ",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
```

I already tried putting `#pageable` at the end, but I get the same error message.

Moving on, Spring generates my query like: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR) AS id, t.name, CAST(COUNT(p.id) AS SMALLINT) AS usedByProjectsCount FROM tag t LEFT JOIN project_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = pt.project_id GROUP BY t.id, t.name) AS t ORDER BY {#pageable} LIMIT ? OFFSET ? , t.usedByProjectsCount desc`

and I need like: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR) AS id, t.name, CAST(COUNT(p.id) AS SMALLINT) AS usedByProjectsCount FROM tag t LEFT JOIN project_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = pt.project_id GROUP BY t.id, t.name) AS t ORDER BY t.usedByProjectsCount desc LIMIT ? OFFSET ? {#pageable}`

I do know the `{#pageable}` attribute should stay there, just so my page values can be placed in the right variables.

Anyway, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the one of my project I have a native query and just put the pageable inside.

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT * " +
            "  FROM (SELECT CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR) AS id, " +
            "               t.name, " + 
            "                CAST(COUNT(p.id) AS SMALLINT) AS usedByProjectsCount " +
            "          FROM tag t " +
            "          LEFT JOIN project_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id " +
            "          LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = pt.project_id " +
            "         GROUP BY t.id, t.name) AS t ",

    countQuery = " SELECT COUNT(*) " + 
                 "        FROM (SELECT 1 " +
                 "                FROM tag t " +
                 "                LEFT JOIN project_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id " +
                 "                LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = pt.project_id " +
                 "               GROUP BY t.id, t.name) AS t ",
    nativeQuery = true)
Page<CustomProjection> customQuery(Pageable pageable)
```

and just call your method with the needed pageRequest.

```
Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.of(Order.desc("usedByProjectsCount"))
```