# Spring Data pagination doesn't work with alias : oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "R" : invalid identifier

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm new to spring. I would like to add pagination to my apis but I keep getting this error

```
 oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "R" : invalid identifier
```

`"R"` is the alias of my table in this query

Repository

```
@Query(
value ="select * from students r inner join conf c on r.status_id = c.id where c.code = 'NEW'", 
nativeQuery = true
)
Page<Student> findNewStudents(Pageable pageable);
```

this is just a simple query but I have also some LONG queries

I searched a lot I found that `countQuery` should be added and effictively it worked for me

```
@Query(
value ="select * from students r inner join conf c on r.status_id = c.id where c.code ='NEW'", 
countQuery ="select count(*) from students r inner join conf c on r.status_id = c.id where c.code = 'NEW'" ,
nativeQuery = true
)
Page<Student> findNewStudents(Pageable pageable);
```

but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68098138/14994239)
`countQuery` is not needed since  Spring Boot **2.4.3** and I'm using  Spring Boot **2.7.1** but I got the error above if don't use it.

as I said with `countQuery` it works but I have some long queries it's bit hard to have the query of counting also!

**UPDATE**

after enabling sql log, I got

```
2022-08-14 23:30:07.384 DEBUG 10996 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL : select * from students r inner join conf c on r.status_id = c.id where c.code ='NEW'  fetch first ? rows only

2022-08-14 23:30:07.525 DEBUG 10996 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL:  select count(r) from students r inner join conf c on r.status_id = c.id where c.code = 'NEW'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To use pagination with native SQL queries declared using the @Query annotation, you need to define the count query by yourself. Visit here: https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-pagination

Comment: enable an sql logging first, to see what queries had been generated by the `Hibernate`

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov I updated my post to include the result of logging, I guess it's because of the `count(r)`. I tried to made `select r.* from students r.. ` but I got  `ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification `

Comment: Sure you'll get - count(r.*) is suppose `group by` existence. I've read an answer to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68098138/7214142) you've linked above. Please read the first comment there! _avoid using table alias in select query, it won't work!_. So I'd propose you to rewrite the query in an old-style comma-separated style join syntax.

Comment: Upd prev answer: not in old-style syntax, but without aliases and with asterisk

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov without alias I got `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`