# Page.getTotalElements() returns the number of total data in table not the number of result of query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, pageable

hi Iam using spring boot, JPA

I used Pageable objects to do Pagination

and when I get each Page, I got totalElements by using `getTotalElements()`

I expected to get the number of searching result, but I got the total number of table's record.

for example, if i have 14 records in my db table and the number of searching result  is `6` ,

- request page =0 size =20

getTotalElements() method returns 6 and getNumberOfElements() method returns 6 so it has no problem in this case

- request page =1 size =20

  getTotalElements() method **returns 14** and getNumberOfElements() method returns 0 so it has **problem in this case**
- request page =0 size =4

  getTotalElements() method **returns 14** and getNumberOfElements() method returns 4 so it has **problem in this case**
- request page =1 size =4

  getTotalElements() method returns 6 and getNumberOfElements() method returns 2 so it has no problem in this case

I don't know why it happens...

data from query is correct but i have no idea why getTotalElements returns the total elements of db records. (and even it's not all the time..)

### service layer

```
 Optional<Page<Club>> clubList = searchRepository.findByConditionsOrderByDate(pointWKT, distance * 1000, state, category, memberNum, regexpTag, pageable);

//and I call getTotalElements() here
```

### repository

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = searchDefaultQuery+ WhereOptionQuery +
            "ORDER BY created_date DESC",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(club_id) FROM club")
    Optional<Page<Club>> findByConditionsOrderByDate (@Param("standard_point") String point, @Param("distance")Integer distance,
                                                      @Param("state")String state, @Param("category")String category, @Param("memberNum")Integer memberNum,
                                                      @Param("tags")String tags, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Your `countQuery` does not have a WHERE clause so it counts every row in the table. In newer Spring Data JPA versions, you [don't need to specify a countQuery for a native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination).

Comment: thank you so much. by deleting countQuery, It works well